# Issue in opening some links in new tab

Tags: html, debugging

Whenever I place `target="_blank"` in my HTML code to open it in a separate tab it opens but does not open the content in the link but automatically redirects to the main page?

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Yes target sorry for the mistake but i have not done any mistake in code,it is running in separate tab but redirects to the main page everytime i open it in separate tab,working fine in same tab

Comment: Please mention full a tag with link..

Comment: @KhurramIshaque i dont understand?? Can you please elaborate.

Comment: I mean, please include the link <a> tag in your question

Comment: Where is your code?